# SQL - returning average number of items by days of the week.

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

The query I have below works fine and returns the items shipped, total days, and average number of items per day.

```
SELECT A.ItemsShipped, A.TotalDays, cast(A.ItemsShipped as float)/cast(A.TotalDays as float) AS     
'Averange items shipped per day' 
FROM(SELECT
    (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM PARTNER_WORKORDER
        WHERE statusNo = 110)
        AS ItemsShipped,
    (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, MIN(orderDt),'2013-11-20 00:00:00.000')
        From PARTNER_WORKORDER)
        AS TotalDays
    )A
```

The question I have now is, how can I get this return the average number of items shipped per each day of the week (average on Monday, average on Tuesday, etc...) so that it ends up returning seven results.  I know there is the way of doing a query for each day, but what would be the efficient way of doing it all in one query?

I am using MS SQLServer for this project.

Thank for any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. I don't have SQL Server instance at hand (so can't validate it), but I guess you get the idea.

```
WITH OrdersPerDay AS (
   SELECT
      CAST(orderDt as INTEGER) as OrderDay,
      COUNT(1) as OrderCount
   FROM PARTNER_WORKORDER
   GROUP BY CAST(orderDt as INTEGER)
   WHERE statusNo = 110
)
SELECT
  DATEPART(dw, CAST(OrderDay as DATETIME)) as WeekDay,
  AVG(OrderCount)
FROM OrdersPerDay
GROUP BY DATEPART(dw, CAST(OrderDay as DATETIME))
```